# Python: How to write to an existing folder in an archive?

Tags: python, zip, archive

I am trying to write to a zip archive that has an existing folder in it. 
So far I have only been able to either:
 `x.write(newfiles)` which gives me `dir1/dir2/dir...n/newfiles`
**OR**
`x.write(newfiles, os.path.rel(newfiles, root))` which gives me all my newfiles in my archive outside of any subdirectories.
However, what I need to accomplish is to have my newfiles write to a subdirectory in my archive that already exists.

Please help! Thanks!

My Code:

```
#create a list of the png files to be added
img_lib = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img_dir):
    for i in files:
        img_lib.append(root + '/' + i)

#open kmz archive for editing in 'append' mode
kmzarc = zipfile.ZipFile(TCP_kmz, mode = 'a')

#loop through list of available png files in img_lib and add to archive
for i in img_lib:
    kmzarc.write(i, 'images/'+os.path.relpath(i, root))

#close file
kmzarc.close()
```

Comment: Update: I have been able to add a new folder with all my newfiles to the archive via x.write(newfiles, 'newfolder/'+os.path.rel(newfiles, root)). However this is deleting all the other existing folders in my archive.